# Назначить теги записям, имеющим в заголовке ключевое слово

Tags: sql, wordpress, mysql

У меня есть много записей без меток, хочу назначить таким записям определенный тег. Если в названии записи найдено определенное слово, то ему присваивается определенный тег. Думаю, это сделать можно через SQL-запрос, но как это реализовать не представляю возможным, ведь теги и записи находятся в разных таблицах. То есть нужно найти записи, соответствующие шаблоны, "взять" их `id`, и этот `id` добавить в таблицу тегов.

Comment: `нужно найти записи, соответствующие шаблонУУУУ, "взять" их id, и этот id добавить в таблицу тегов.` Наверно так.

Comment: Но как хоть примерно это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Давайте для того, чтобы вопрос был менее абстрактным введем три таблицы:

- `names` - записи
- `tags` - тэги
- `tags_names` - связующая таблица записей и тэгов

Вот минимальный дамп базы данных с этими таблицами

```
CREATE TABLE `names` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Статья'),
(2, 'PHP'),
(3, 'Статья по MySQL');

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'php'),
(2, 'mysql');

CREATE TABLE `tags_names` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tags_names` (`id`, `tag_id`, `name_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1);
```

У нас есть три статьи, два тэга и лишь одна статья связана с обоими тэгами. Две других статьи должны быть связаны со своими тэгами, но этой связи нет. В этом легко убедиться при помощи следующего запроса (выводится только первый тэг)

```
SELECT
  names.id AS name_id,
  names.name AS name,
  tags.name AS tags
FROM
  names
LEFT JOIN
  tags_names
ON
  names.id = tags_names.name_id
LEFT JOIN
  tags
ON
  tags.id = tags_names.tag_id
GROUP BY
  names.id;
+---------+-------------------------+------+
| name_id | name                    | tags |
+---------+-------------------------+------+
|       1 | Статья                  | php  |
|       2 | PHP                     | NULL |
|       3 | Статья по MySQL         | NULL |
+---------+-------------------------+------+
```

Для того, чтобы связать статьи с тэгами, давайте сначала найдем статьи без тэгов:

```
SELECT
  names.id AS id,
  names.name AS name
FROM
  names
LEFT JOIN
  tags_names
ON
  names.id = tags_names.name_id
WHERE
  tags_names.tag_id IS NULL;
+----+-------------------------+
| id | name                    |
+----+-------------------------+
|  2 | PHP                     |
|  3 | Статья по MySQL         |
+----+-------------------------+
```

Связать полученные статьи с тэгами можно при помощи оператора `LIKE`. Нам придется динамически сформировать шаблон для `LIKE` при помощи функции

```
`CONCAT()`.
SELECT
  names.id AS name_id,
  names.name AS name,
  tags.id AS tag_id,
  tags.name AS tag
FROM
  names
LEFT JOIN
  tags_names
ON
  names.id = tags_names.name_id
LEFT JOIN
  tags
ON
  names.name LIKE CONCAT('%', tags.name, '%')
WHERE
  tags_names.tag_id IS NULL;
+---------+-------------------------+--------+-------+
| name_id | name                    | tag_id | tag   |
+---------+-------------------------+--------+-------+
|       2 | PHP                     |      1 | php   |
|       3 | Статья по MySQL         |      2 | mysql |
+---------+-------------------------+--------+-------+
```

Как видно из результов предыдущего запроса статье "PHP" был назначен тэг "php", а статье "Статья по MySQL" - тэг "mysql". Теперь нам остается только записать результат при помощи оператора `INSERT ... SELECT ...`

```
INSERT INTO tags_names
SELECT
  NULL,
  tags.id AS tag_id,
  names.id AS name_id
FROM
  names
LEFT JOIN
  tags_names
ON
  names.id = tags_names.name_id
LEFT JOIN
  tags
ON
  names.name LIKE CONCAT('%', tags.name, '%')
WHERE
  tags_names.tag_id IS NULL;
```

Теперь если мы запросим список статей и соответствующих им тэгов, можно убедиться, что они назначены корректно

```
SELECT
  names.id AS name_id,
  names.name AS name,
  tags.name AS tags
FROM
  names
LEFT JOIN
  tags_names
ON
  names.id = tags_names.name_id
LEFT JOIN
  tags
ON
  tags.id = tags_names.tag_id
GROUP BY
  names.id;
+---------+-------------------------+-------+
| name_id | name                    | tags  |
+---------+-------------------------+-------+
|       1 | Статья                  | php   |
|       2 | PHP                     | php   |
|       3 | Статья по MySQL         | mysql |
+---------+-------------------------+-------+
```